Carbon Design System Package for in Nuxt has no style
I am trying to use the Carbon Design System Components for the first time, and I want to use it in a nuxt project. I have installed carbon type, styles, icons, and vue (@carbon/vue , @carbon/icons, @carbon/type, @carbon/styles). I also added carbon-vue.ts to my plugins folder. The documentation is not clear on how to use it so I'm asking here.
The problem is that nothing has any styling. it seems like all the styling and properties are gone. Should I install something else beside it or did I do it wrong?

Hard to help without a [repro] or any leads for errors/warnings.

@kissu it's not even code just installing it does not have any styling.

There are actually an infinite amount of combinations with packages. The issue here is not the styling itself but the project configuration. This is as relevant as any kind of styling in terms of reproductions.
